# To get selected list box value with folder path

Tags: c#

I have a list box and its populated by this method,

```
private void ToReadFromExcel_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string folderpath = @"\\gibson\users";
    // Call the method to show available files
    PopulateListBox(ExcelListBox, folderpath, "*.csv");
}

// To populate list box with csv files from given path
private void PopulateListBox(ListBox lsb, string Folder, string FileType)
{
    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(Folder);
    FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles(FileType);
    foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        lsb.Items.Add(file.Name);
    }
}

String strItem;
foreach (Object selecteditem in ExcelListBox.SelectedItems)
{
    strItem = selecteditem as String;
    MessageBox.Show(strItem);
}
// read csv file information and insert into detail table
string filepath = @"\\gibson\users\CampManager.csv";
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filepath);
```

I hard coded the file path now, but I need to pass the filepath that was selected in the listbox. I have the file name in the variable `stritem`. If I want to pass the whole folder path how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an ideal way. You should, instead of adding the `FileInfo` object's `Name`, should add the `FileInfo` object itself. So later **you will be able to retrieve any piece of info related to that object, in your case say size, parent folder etc**, and not just file name. Do it like this:

```
// To populate list box with csv files from given path
private void PopulateListBox(ListBox lsb, string Folder, string FileType)
{
    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(Folder);
    FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles(FileType);
    foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        lsb.Items.Add(file); //<-- note here
    }
}

String strItem;
foreach (FileInfo selecteditem in ExcelListBox.SelectedItems)
{
     StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(selecteditem.FullName);
     //or whatever
}
```

One thing you should take care of here is to set the [`DisplayMember`](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx&ei=78XLUKmnGY3IrQe1pICQAw&usg=AFQjCNG1GWgVepFO-XVcA2kA8Mu-PxMTHQ&sig2=OUf6QfHuctPyP6YhJlpYFQ&bvm=bv.1355325884,d.bmk) property of the ListBox like this:

```
ExcelListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

What this does is to set the what property of the object in the listbox should be displayed. So here you choose `FileInfo.Name` which is what you want. This is how typically custom objects are added to ListBoxes in WinForms. You do not add just the string part of it typically. Akin to `DisplayMember`, there is also `ValueMember` property which is used to assign a value for each object, probably some id or so, but in your case nothing.

**Few suggestions**, 1) If you're using .NET 4, then use [`EnumerateFiles`](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDYQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles.aspx&ei=HsjLUOjgIYrmrAf9y4GYBg&usg=AFQjCNEEpYCkzNL3QfCEy1ku95ijrSH1ZA&sig2=u_220Y6EDxTjSXtOra4dWg&bvm=bv.1355325884,d.bmk) instead of `GetFiles`. The former is lazy and only yields a result when you start enumerating them (not beforehand), so it should be faster.

```
foreach (FileInfo file in dinfo.EnumerateFiles(FileType)) //<-- note here
{
    lsb.Items.Add(file); 
}
```

2) Use a `using` clause to dispose your stream reader properly, since that wont lock your file. It's always a good practice to make use of `using`. Its better on eyes than manual closing and disposing! Like this or so:

```
foreach (FileInfo selecteditem in ExcelListBox.SelectedItems)
{
     using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(selecteditem.FullName))
     {
         //your code here
     }
}
```